# How to translate full page in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

Usually when i use the translator services, i have an eventsubscriber in order to translate the locale from the user preferences, stored in the request as _locale. This works for words or phrases, Through yaml files as messages or validators. But imagine that you have a privacy policy.

Which is the best way in order to translate a full page using the translator services in symfony 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something which is an entire page, I'd often have a separate template, or at least a part-page that would be included in the page whole.

You can get the _locale from $request, and then choose a different template, based on it. At its simplest, `$this->twig->renderResponse("privacy.{$locale}.html.twig");`, or pass it in and switch an included template in the page-level content.

For dynamic template names, I've done something similar before - this is a simplified version (mine had two variables, not just `$place`).

```
$tplName = "policies/privacy_{$place}.html.twig";
if (!$this->twig->exists($tplName)) {
    $tplName = "policies/privacy_uk.html.twig";
    $place = 'uk';
}

return $this->twig->renderResponse($tplName, ['place' => $place]);
```

Equally, you could pass `$tplName` into the rendering as a variable, and use that as a parameter to include a partial template.

Comment: This is my code:/**
     * @Route("{_locale}/privacy-policy", name="privacy_policy")
     * @Route()
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $locale = $request->getLocale();
        return $this->render("privacy_policy/privacy_{$locale}.html.twig");
    }            thanks